# Verbatim in comparative sentence. Which preposition should I use?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Looking at some examples of the usage of the word verbatim, I found cases where you talk about a single object (a piece of text for example) and use verbatim as an adverb as a synonim of "exactly, to the letter"

[https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/verbatim#:~:text=If%20you%20repeat%20something%20verbatim,in%20the%20state%2Drun%20newspapers.&text=Verbatim%20is%20also%20an%20adjective,conversation%20she's%20had%20this%20week](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/verbatim#:%7E:text=If%20you%20repeat%20something%20verbatim,in%20the%20state%2Drun%20newspapers.&text=Verbatim%20is%20also%20an%20adjective,conversation%20she%27s%20had%20this%20week).

> If you repeat something verbatim, you use exactly the same words as
> were used originally.
>
> The President's speeches are regularly reproduced verbatim in the
> state-run newspapers

I would like to use verbatim in a comparative sentence, but I'm not sure which preposition verbatim needs to use:

Example:

> This text is exactly like the ancient one

> This text is identical to the ancient one

> This text is verbatim (as/to/like/[blank]?) the ancient one

Can verbatim be used to compare things like this? How should I use it if I want to say that two texts are identical in content?

Comment: You mean _preposition_ and not _pronoun_, don't you?

Comment: yes, corrected, thanks

Comment: Without the "is," *This text matches the ancient one verbatim.*

Comment: But note, if the "ancient" one is in a different language to the "modern" one, then the latter is *not* a verbatim recital of the former.

Comment: In the case @DanBron refers to, we would say something like "literal translation of".

Answer (score 3):

**Verbatim with**

Verbatim is rarely used in this manner, with an explicit comparison. You would say "This text is verbatim" (with the reference assumed from context), or "This text is a verbatim copy of the ancient one".

However, I have found some old examples of "verbatim with".

"A Chapter on the Harmonizing Gospels" by "The Late Duke of Manchester" in *The Journal of Sacred Literature* in 1857 has several instances of "verbatim with the Septuagint" for quotations that are identical in the Septuagint and the text under discussion.

Google Books has [a 1816 copy](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Works_of_William_Shakspeare/AHg4AAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) of *The Complete Works of Shakespeare* which claims to be "collated verbatim with the most authentic copies".

So "with" was used at least in the 19th century.

Comment: Valuable as historical research, but the caveat about 'verbatim with' being rare / unidiomatic (and hence best avoided in modern writing) is even more helpful.